# How to capture first column values of a command?

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I am trying to write a script that is suppose to run a command and use for loop to capture first column of the output and do further processing.

command: `tst get files`

output of this command is something like

```
NAME        COUNT           ADMIN
FileA.txt   30              adminA
FileB.txt   21              local
FileC.txt   9               local
FileD.txt   90              adminA
```

Here is what I have tried so far : **UPDATED** also want to run additional commands

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(tst get files)
do
    echo "FILE :[${f}]"
    tst setprimary ${f} && tst get dataload
done
```

the output I am seeing is something like

```
FILE :[NAME]
FILE :[COUNT]
FILE :[ADMIN]
FILE :[FileA.txt]
FILE :[30]
FILE :[adminA]
FILE :[FileB.txt]
FILE :[21]
FILE :[local]
FILE :[FileC.txt]
FILE :[9]
FILE :[local]
FILE :[FileD.txt]
FILE :[90]
FILE :[adminA]
```

I am looking for an output something like

```
FILE :[FileA.txt]
FILE :[FileB.txt]
FILE :[FileC.txt]
FILE :[FileD.txt]
```

What should I modify in the shell script to only capture NAME column values? Am I executing the tst get files command correctly in the for loop or is there a better way to execute a command and loop thru the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
tst get files | awk 'NR > 1 { printf "FILE :[%s]\n", $1 }'
```

---

**Update:** To answer extended problem as per comments below by OP:

```
while read -r file _; do
    tst setprimary "$file" && tst get dataload 
done < <(tst get files)
```

Comment: If I use this approach, is it possible to run follow up commands? Lets say I want to run following two commands for each filename "tst setprimary <filename>" and tst get dataload

Comment: The reason I framed the question like that is because I assumed I would need a for loop to run further commands using the input from outer command. But after seeing your answer, I got curious to see if there is any alternate option like chaining everything in a single line instead of for loop

Comment: This did the trick. How did the $file variable pick up the first column automatically?

Comment: It is because we're using `read file _` which means capture first field in `file` and ignore rest.

Comment: How do I skip the first row? I want to skip the header row that starts with "NAME". If I do an extra read before the while loop, is that a better practice?

Comment: You can use `done < <(tst get files | sed '1d')` in last line

Answer (score 6):

EDIT (Samuel Kirschner): you can do without the for loop entirely and just use `awk` to print the lines you're interested in

```
tst get files | awk 'NR > 1 {print "FILE :[" $1 "]"}'
```

If you want to keep the for loop for some reason and just extract the file name from the lines while skipping the header, you have a few choices. Awk is probably the easiest because of the `NR` builtin variable (which counts lines) and automatic field-splitting (`$1` refers to the first field in the line, for instance), but you can use `sed` and `cut` as well.

You can use `awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}'` to get the first column (using any whitespace character as a delimiter while skipping the first line) or `sed 1d | cut -d$'\t' -f1`. Note that `$'\t'` is bash-specific syntax for a literal tab character, if your file is padded with spaces rather than using tabs to delimit fields, you can't use the `sed ... | cut ...` example.

i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(tst get files | awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}')
do
    echo "FILE :[${f}]"
done
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in $(tst get files | sed 1d | cut -d$'\t' -f1)
do
    echo "FILE :[${f}]"
done
```

to avoid unnecessary splitting in the `for` loop. It's best to set IFS to something specific outside the loop body to prevent `'a file with whitespace.txt'` from being broken up.

```
OLD_IFS=IFS
IFS=$'\n\t'

for f in $(tst get files | sed 1d | cut -d$'\t' -f1)
do
    echo "FILE :[${f}]"
done
```

Comment: why not just: `tst get files | awk 'NR > 1 {print "FILE :[" $1 "]"}'`?

Comment: I have to run a bunch of other commands with some if else blocks by using ${f} as input inside the for loop, so thinking for loop might be cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Or perl:

```
tst ... | perl -lanE 'say "File: [$F[0]]" if $.>1'
```

- the variable `$.` contains the current line number